# Why is xmlResponse.documentElement returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have following JavaScript code snippet which reads a dynamically created XML file by a php script and writes text accordingly in destination html page.

```
    function process()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {

        var user = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
        var url = "http://localhost/dashboard/x/js/login.php?user="+user;
        xmlHttp.open("GET",url, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}
    function handleServerResponse()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0)
        {
            if(xmlHttp.status==200)
            {
                xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
                xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
                alert(xmlDocumentElement);
                message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
                document.getElementById("errorprompt").innerHTML = message;
                setTimeout('process()', 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }
```

also the login.php file is as below-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
echo '<root>';
    $user=$_GET['user'];
    $userArray=array("vishalkhare39@gmail.com","khare39vishal@rediffmail.com");
    if(in_array($user,$userArray))
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">;</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>';
    else
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">;</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>';
echo '</root>';
?>
```

My problem is straightforward. I am not able to print appropriate data at targeted div in my index.html.
I have narrowed it down to identify the cause for is.
It is because in my javascript code the line `xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;` is actually saving Undefined in `xmlDocumentElement` i.e. `xmlResponse.documentElement` is returning undefined. which it clearly should not.

I just want a remedy for this. I understand that it is caused by XML not rendering properly. But it is not the case here. My XML is rendering properly on chrome as well as on firefox (Attached JPEG). [image]
Please indicate the actual reason and how to resolve it. **Please do not redirect me any other webpages or links. I have wasted enough hours on this to know that there is no appropriate answere anywhere.**

Comment: Change `.responseText` to `.responseXML`. Then you can apply native selector methods against it.

Comment: Thank You so much @Ohgodwhy
It worked. However now the line `message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;` seems to be NOT working properly.
variable `message` is storing value `undefined`.
any Ideas?

Comment: I have updated the function `handleServerResponse()` as follows-
`function handleServerResponse()
{
 if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0)
 {
  if(xmlHttp.status==200)
  {
   xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
   message=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0].childNodes[0];
   document.getElementById("errorprompt").innerHTML = message;
  }
  else
  {
   alert("something went wrong");
  }
 }
}`
But it just sets the variable `message` to store `[object element]`.
It prints the same. I am not able to figure out how to reach exact data in my XML.